# ImageView background too large

Tags: android, image, background, imageview

I am making an android application that needs to set a background color on ImageView. The images are plain white squares with transparent parts (a kind of mask), but I see the background "overflowing" the borders, making an outline. How can I fix that ?

Thank you !

The relevant XML code is the following :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tile1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/hexagon"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/hexagon_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/hexagon_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="#ffff000b"/>
```

(`hexagon_horizontal_margin` is set to 4dp)

The image is 100x100 px and this is how it looks in the emulator :

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you post a link to your hexagon drawable? If its background is transparent, then I'd expect to see the background all around it. However, it looks to me like the drawable has a white background.

Comment: @Vincenator The hexagon is a white square with a "hole" of transparency in the shape of a hexagon : [http://up.tuetuopay.fr/stackoverflow/hexagon.png](http://up.tuetuopay.fr/stackoverflow/hexagon.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your hexagon drawable. The outer pixels of each side of your Drawable are transparent. So when you set a color as background. Those pixels let the background color show. Edit your drawable to remove that transparency and it's done.

Try with this drawable here:

[image: Try with this one :D]

Comment: That was it. When I created the Hexagon in Photoshop, I left the "Anti-alias" checkbox checked (for the inner edges), but it also smoothed the outer edges ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your hexagon drawable. If you look closely at the edges, you'll see that the white overlay fades to slight transparency. The `ImageView` itself is working.